# Is there a relation between norm defined on a vector space V and norm defined on its boundary?

Tags: convex-optimization, normed-spaces, signal-processing, boundary-value-problem, hypergeometric-function

Suppose that a norm is defined on a subspace $V$ of a vector space based on the following inner product

$$\langle u, v\rangle_{V}=\int_V u v \quad d V .$$

Suppose that S is the boundary of V. I would like to write $\| u\|_S$ in terms of a norm in the space $V$. In other words, can we find any relation between $\| u\|_S$ and $\| U\|_V$, for some $U$ in $V$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not even sure there is such thing as the "boundary" of a vector space.

Comment: what do you mean by boundary of a vector space?

Comment: I just edited my question. Suppose it is a subspace of the whole vector space. Suppose that the norm is defined on $V$ and a relation is needed for the norm defined on the boundary of $V$. Very simply,think of $V$ to be a volume in $\mathbf{R}^3$. I need a relation between the norm which is defined over $V$ and the norm which is defined on the boundary of the surface of $V$. In other words, if you take the volume as a sphere, I am looking for a relation between the norm on the sphere and the norm on the circle surrounding the surface of the sphere.